# Multiple Controls Drag and Drop to the Same Destination

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am using the below code to drag and drop the elements in an application.But most of the times it is dropping to the different section of the page.And in rarely its placing the element to the correct destination.The issue is coming when moving the third element to its destination. From third element onwards, the element is getting dropped in different path.The xpath of the all the three elements are exactly same.I am dragging 7 elements totally.From 4th element onwards the area of the destination is changing.So the issue is the third element is getting moved to the area where the 4th element should go.

The code upto 4th element is updated below

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/button")); 

WebElement target1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element1, target1).perform();

Thread.sleep(7000);     


WebElement element2= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/button")); 

WebElement target2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element2, target2).perform();

Thread.sleep(7000);     


WebElement element3= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/button")); 

WebElement target3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element3, target3).perform();

Thread.sleep(7000);


WebElement element4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div/button")); 

WebElement target4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element4, target4).perform();

Thread.sleep(7000);
```

Comment: Specify which application or website were you using @Lipson so that it will be a good reference for me to understand and help you directly. :)

Comment: Its for an application  which i am working professionally.It's a page to perform pivot operations same like the pivot in excel.It has all the available fields and the user needs to drag and drop the field as per his requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try this way and also use relative xpath for better understanding.

For example, In your case there are seven different elements needs to do perform drag and drop operation so, first step should be define different elements like `source element 1`. In below code snippet i have define only two source elements for better explanations.

Your second step should be define the destination path. for this refer below code snippet `destination element`

Your third step should be Based on your locator(id,xpath) create an int or string array for reducing the numbers of lines of code. Then use for loop, so number of times for loop will be execute the same code.

For more details on this, refer below mentioned code snippet.

```
WebElement element_1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-lobid='12']"));      //source element 1

WebElement element_2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-lobid='21']"));     //source element 2

WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lobModalPopUp']/div"));  //destination path

int[] array_source = new int[]{12,21};  // create fixed array for id number of source element 1 and 2

for(int i = 0; i<array_source.length; i++)  //Passing id number of source element 1 and 2 inside the for loop.
{
        WebElement all_source_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-lobid='"+arraylobs[i]+"']"));  // getting all source element with the help of fixed array.

        Actions drag = new Actions(driver);
        drag.clickAndHold(all_source_element).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        drag.clickAndHold().moveToElement(destination).release(destination).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
}
```